# programmatically create UITableViewController IOS 5

Tags: ios5, uitableview

When starting a new project (single view based), I began to get a strange crash when attempting to use a custom UITableViewController. The custom UITableViewController works just fine in other application started a while back, but now it seems to fail when used in new projects.

This is how I am instantiating the UITableViewController:

```
TestViewController * tableViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
[self.view addSubview:tableViewController.tableView];
```

The compiler is a lot more strict now, so I make sure to add the required protocols in the headers as follows:

```
@interface TestViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
```

I get the following message:

```
-[__NSMallocBlock__ numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x654dcd0
```

In the implementation for the custom UITableViewController, I am hard coding the number of section and rows, but I am still getting this problem.

I don't know where to go from here, I appreciate any help I can get, 
Thanks